# Multiple Kernels using Enthought Canopy (python)

Tags: python, kernel, canopy

I'm using Enthought Canopy to run my python code. On one computer I want to run 3 different python codes, all completely independently (for 3 different instruments), simultaneously. I seem to only be able to run one code at a time in Canopy with one kernel. How do I run more at the same time?

I have read in a thread about using ipython qtconsole, but I don't know what this is. I can't even find this file on my pc. Can anyone step me through the process of how to get these codes all running on multiple kernels?

Comment: `File> New Editor Window`

Comment: While this does open a new window and the code separately, it does not launch a new kernel. For instance, the green 'run' button does not appear when I run a code from another editor window.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/47316983/1988991