# Run scripts simultaniously in Canopy

Tags: python, python-3.x, kernel, canopy

This is an update request on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18572379/multiple-kernels-in-enthought-canopy) 4 year old question.

I have been using Canopy for many years but one draw back is that I can't debug a different project while another is running. I often run code that takes about an hour so it would be ideal to be able to run one project while working on another. In short, I would like to use multiple kernels integrated with the IDE. Perhaps as many as three as I have four cores.

Canopy is my default an only python on my windows machine. I am using Canopy 2.1.3 with python 3.5

Comment: Just found potential duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34902261/multiple-kernels-using-enthought-canopy-python Updated tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The use-case is clear, but is not yet implemented, though it is getting closer. (Canopy 2.1 can work with multiple different environments, but not yet simultaneously.) I do expect multiple simultaneous running kernels to be available in 2018. Meanwhile, the workaround is the same as before -- develop and test your code in the Canopy GUI, but run your long production runs in Canopy Command Prompts using qtconsole or ipython or plain python.

The current version of Canopy is 2.1.6

FWIW: as a feature request, I'm not sure that this is really an SO-question.

Comment: Thanks! A short tutorial on how to runs in Canopy Command Prompt would be useful as I have never done this. It could not be as simple at "python PATH/file.py"

Comment: I did some test and it is that easy to do from the Canopy Command Prompt. Plotting popups even work. :)

Comment: Thanks, good suggestion for a (very!) short tutorial. Ticketed.

Comment: I realize you already said this is not the place for feature requests so I am just going to point out that it is annoying that the Canopy Command Prompt will not expand to full screen width, at least on windows. :)

Comment: It's just using cmd.exe, so that depends on your Windows version. In Windows 7, you can configure it like any other Command Prompt window (search google). In Windows 10, it's more dynamically flexible. Or you can use a console enhancer like conemu which lets you configure all kinds of things about your console windows.

Comment: This method is broken in Canopy 2.1.9.3717 for Python 3.5. I am getting an error when I "import matplotlib.pyplot" . 

ImportError: No module named 'PySide'

ImportError: Matplotlib qt-based backends require an external PyQt4, PyQt5,
or PySide package to be installed, but it was not found.

None of these packages are available in the package manager and the pip install from the command prompt is failing for all three

Comment: PySide does not exist for Python 3.x (PySide2, aka "Qt for Python" is in good shape but is not yet available in Canopy). Instead, import PyQt from the Canopy Package manager. See [this related article](https://support.enthought.com/hc/en-us/articles/115001655566-Python-3-in-Canopy-2-No-module-named-PyQt4-error)